# Demean column values of a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to demean the values of a pandas DataFrame.

However, my code

```
test_scores = df[test_score_vars]
test_score_means = test_scores.mean()
print(test_scores.sub(test_score_means, axis='columns').mean())
```

does not return the expected list of zeroes, but instead raises this error

```
ValueError: cannot broadcast shape [(21409,)] with block values [(1,)]
```

I tried to follow the documentation but I do not understand where I got the shapes wrong.

So, how can I demean my values with pandas?

Comment: what does demean mean? it looks like you are trying to subtract all values from the mean correct? so why not just `test_scores.sub(test_scores.mean())`

Comment: It is easier for people to answer if you provide a small example that illustrates what you are trying to do.

Comment: Do you want to demean each column? Or subtract the overall dataframe mean from each value?

Comment: Maybe telling the data some degrading jokes will help demean it? Ask it how many rows it needs to screw in a light bulb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that the values of my dataframe were categorical. I read in the data using `read_stata`, so I have to set `convert_categoricals=False` and `preserve_dtypes=False` to make sure that the values are floats.

With the correct dtypes, `test_scores.sub(test_scores.mean())` does the job.

Thank you for your comments!